# Полиморфизм объекта. Как подвергнуть полиморфизму не метод класса а конкретного объекта?

Tags: python

```
Cat Tom = new Cat() { 
    @Override
    public String say() { return "Meau! Meau!  MEAU!!!"; }
};
```

Это код из джавы. Можно ли провернуть такую фичу на питоне и подвергнуть полиморфизму не метод класса а конкретного объекта, и как?

Comment: Не существует полиморфизма на уровне объекта. В этом примере неявно создаётся новый анонимный (безымянный) класс.

Answer (score 3):

Это такая короткая запись производного класса с одним перекрытым методом.

На Питоне просто заведите производный класс и перекройте метод вручную. (В Питоне, как и в Джаве, методы классов по сути виртуальные.)

Answer (score 2):

*Python* и *Java* - разные языки и подходы к решению одной и той же задачи могут отличаться. В данном случае можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что в языке *Python* у каждого объекта можно менять (почти) любое свойство, в том числе и переопределять методы класса:

```
class Test:
    def say(self):
        print("class Test")

test = Test()

test2 = Test()
test2.say = lambda: print("test2")

test.say()
test2.say()
```

Вывод этой программы:

> class Test
>
> test2

Comment: Ого, круто, не знал.